# give a value of the distribution in input and get the quantile in R

Tags: r, distribution, quantile

Is there a way to give a value of the distribution in input and get the quantile of this distribution in R?

Thanks

Comment: Which distribution? Look at the `q`* and `p`* functions.

Answer (score 1):

Please be more specific, which kind of distribution are we talking about?

Here you can find a list of the most famous avaiable in R : [Avaiable Distributions](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/Distributions.html)

You just need to write q before the name, like so:

```
value = 0.05
qnorm(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear, so I am assuming that you are asking about the probability of getting a certain value for the normal distribution or getting the distribution's value at a certain percentile.

Let's assume that we have the log return of Apple's stock and that the return is normally distributed with a mean of **0.1** and standard deviation of **0.6**.

The probability of getting a return which is less than or equal **0%** in a given month, can be obtained using the following built-in function in R:

```
pnorm(0, mean = 0.1, sd = 0.6) # P(X=return <= 0%)
# 43%
```

The 95th percentile of the distribution of the return can be found as following:

```
qnorm(0.95, mean=0.1, sd = 0.6)
# 1.08
```

If you are working with another distribution such as binomial distribution, then you would want to use: **pbinom** and **qbinom** functions.

Comment: This is what I want but the problem is that my distribution is not normal (fat tails). I was looking for something like 'pquantile(myvalue in my distribution) = 0.85%'

Comment: Hello Henry, your question is still unclear to me. Have you tried using the built-in function **quantile()**?



    `x= c(1:10)`
  `quantile(x,probs = .5)`
`#5.5 which is the median`